# Alpha Layer + Transparency Shader Glitch in Eevee

Tags: shaders, transparency, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

I am following the CG Geek tutorial in which he details modeling a tree in one minute. (https://youtu.be/y7PdiGXbrD0)

I'm running into problems when it comes to shading. When I add a transparent shader to my tree-branch texture, the alpha layer becomes opaque. Here is my node set-up and the result.

[image]

[image]

I've tried adjusting the blending mode settings in the material window. Going from "Alpha Blend" to "Alpha Clip" does result in the opaque alpha layer disappearing, but it introduces some strange artifacting involving white dots (they appear to be the outline of the alpha-layered image textures).

[image]

This is all in EEVEE. When I switch to Cycles, these issues go away, but my GPU pays the price with all the branches being rendered. Any suggestions for trouble-shooting are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your nodes are wrong (you're using Transparent Shader instead of Translucent). Here, from the tutorial you are referring to:

[image]

Comment: Great catch--I didn't realize I made that mistake. Unfortunately, the problem persists. Hundreds of small white dots when on alpha clip, and the full opaque layer of the alpha channel on alpha blend.

Comment: Did you check your source texture alpha in photoshop or Gimp?

Comment: Yessir! The alpha layer is as it should be, a 0% opacity value.

Comment: well, may be test your image texture in Blender with a fresh default scene and the most basic alpha material: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhNI.jpg